# UICollectionViewController not getting parent attribute

Tags: swift

I'm having a problem with accessing the parent attribute from a child `UICollectionViewController` attribute.

The parent is a `ChildViewController` of a modal, and the code in which it adds the `UICollectionViewController` looks like

```
let assetPickerController = AssetGridViewController(collectionViewLayout: GridFlowLayout())
addChildViewController(assetPickerController)
let childView = assetPickerController.view!
assetPickerController.par = self
assetPickerController.nav = self.navigationController
assetPickerController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

and the `AssetGridViewController` has the following code, which prints nil

```
let svc = self as! UIViewController
let parentSize = svc.parent!.view.frame.size
print(parentSize)
```

but it can get the `par` property (which I made myself). I'm not too sure why this is happening, is this a `UICollectionViewController` problem, or is it happening because it's a child of a child of a modal?

Comment: so whats your issue ? parentzise you are not getting in child view ?

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in the question, but I edited it. The point was that the code couldn't access its parent property, and I wasn't sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the parent size as attribute of the class.

Add the attribute

```
var parentSize
```

into assetPickerController, so you can do

```
assetPickerController.parentSize = self.view.frame.size //Before didMove
assetPickerController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```